# C String Infinite For Loop For Small C[]

Tags: c++

Why does c-string length matter when using for loops? Is there an issue with the termination character '\0'?

The following code sends the for loop into a crazy loop that crashes the compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c[] = "charac";
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By adding a 't' to my c-string, the code runs perfectly fine:

```
    char c[] = "charact";
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Did you add 't' or not?

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching that. I just edited the question.

Comment: Note that it is not the compiler that crashes; it is the program generated from your (faulty) source code that crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version, there is no character `c[7]`. You have 7 characters in the array, 6 characters of string and 1 null terminator:

```
Array:   c h a r a c \0
Indices: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Attempting to access anything beyond that is undefined behavior.

In your second version, assuming the code you're running has the `t` you forgot to put in the posted version, the array has 8 characters, and the loop stays within the bounds of the array.

Comment: but he adds only 't', so no c[7] called after revise?

Comment: @linpingta: The t brings the length of the array up to 8.

Comment: I guess I was just wondering what the "undefined behavior" would be. Apparently, it is a spazzy compilation. But it seems like it has to do only with the overstepping the length, not with the actual content (i.e. the null character).

Comment: This is just me practicing around with c-strings for the first time, and I was experimenting with different inputs and output behaviors. Actually, I'm trying to dynamically fit the for loop to match different sized strings, so that was a bit of practice.

Comment: @Mikael_SFSU: Undefined behavior can be pretty much anything. The standard hyperbole is that the computer is allowed to [make demons fly out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @user2357112 I appreciate your levity, and I noticed that the computer's "undefined behavior" truly is undefinable. Great link, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string of length 7 (6 + null terminator), and are attempting to access an 8th element.  This will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Would this happen with any type of array? Or is it only c-strings? 
I'm thinking the answer to the first question is "no, because other arrays are initialized to 0 by default, but c-strings don't have anything after the \0".

Comment: Accessing any array out of bounds is undefined behavior.  In this particular case, you are default initializing the array to a compiler-determined size of 7.  When you do it to a size of 8, your loop no longer goes out of bounds.  This would happen with any array.  Your loop condition should only loop over valid elements for the array you are iterating.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are stepping past the end of the end of your character array. By adding the extra character, your string is now 7 characters long so the i<8 test works.

Answer (score 1):

You are index past the end of the array. C starts indexing at zero so the last index of a six character string is five. If you include the null terminator then you have six but you are accessing the seventh array position.

Answer (score 0):

c[7] doesn't exist for "charac" as c[6] is the null terminating character. But when you change it to "charact" then c[7] becomes the null terminating character so it runs fine.